# When should one do class rebalancing?

Tags: regression, inference, binary-data

Does anybody know a source when class rebalancing should be considered?

Say one has a very small dataset. About 70 observations.
When would class rebalancing make sense?

When the 0/1 ratio is 70/30, 80/20, ...

For such small sample sizes, would e.g. bootstrapping even be appropriate?

Best

Comment: What do you mean by "rebalancing"?

Comment: Never. [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)